# How do Fragment Backstacks persist and how to restore them?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack, android-nested-fragment

I have a few related questions, regarding how fragment backstacks persist in android, and, when they're lost, how to go about restoring them.

Scenario 1: A fragment F has a complex nested fragment UI, with associated backstack (ie, accessible via getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack()).  At the root level, FragmentTransaction.replace() is called replacing F with G.  Later, the transaction is reversed, and F is inserted (to my knowledge, created if it was not retained).  What is the state of F's childManager's backstack?  If it is empty, how could I have best stored this to restore it, leaving F in exactly the same state it was in when it was replaced?

Scenario 2: Activity 1 starts Activity 2 via startActivity().  The user finishes in Activity 2 and back-buttons to Activity 1 (or possibly returns via onActivityResult()).  What is the state of Activity 1's fragment backstack (either for getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager(), if a support library FragmentActivity)?  If the answer is that the backstack is now empty: how could Activity 1 have best saved its backstack to restore it, so that the Activity is in the exact same state it was in when it was left?

Scenario 3: Same as Scenario 2, but now treating fragments in the activity and their childManager's backstacks (as in 1).

I'm hoping to find out about worst case scenarios - i.e. things "may still be in memory", but might they have gone?  etc.